# Executing code when Application is updated/reinstalled

Tags: android

I have Some Alarms set via AlarmManager to do some periodic jobs.
I set/reset them when user opens the app for the first time & on every boot_complete event.
But when the app is reinstalled via ADB then my alarms do not fire anymore. looks like the OS deletes the Alarms on reinstall of the app. I assume this will happen if the user updates the app from the market also.

If I can receive a broadcast or some sort of callback in the event of reinstall/upgrade etc of my application, I can set the alarms again. but i don't know if it is possible or how?
Can someone please help me out.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible.

You can create a broadcast receiver that listens for any `PACKAGE_*`  events the system sends, but you won't receive them for your own application except for when your application is being upgraded — you'll get `PACKAGE_REMOVED` followed soon after by [`PACKAGE_REPLACED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED).

Comment: Thanks, i'll try to handle these events n see if it works for me. But i still don't agree with this a default behavior. Why are the alarms removed when every other data like prefs & sqlite db is maintained(even given a chance to upgrade in case of DB) when upgrading/reinstalling the app. This just adds an unnecessary overhead on the programmer.

Comment: DB upgrades don't happen at application upgrade time. Anyway, you could file a bug on the Android project to let them know that you think alarms should be kept when replacing a package. I can't think of anything immediately obvious why this couldn't be done, as even if the PendingIntent in your alarm can't be resolved after the upgrade, then the system could just ignore it..

Comment: I have the exact same problem. The PACKAGE_REPLACED intent might fire when the replacement happens via Market (or some other mechanism) but AFAICS it doesn't when the replacement happens via ADB; I see the PACKAGE_REMOVED followed by the PACKAGE_ADDED events, neither of which can be caught by the package itself (according to the docs).